# Global variable assignment in python class

Tags: python, oop, beautifulsoup

My XmlParser receive file name and then read by filename and then create my soup for different methods. I try to make soup global variable. But I refer to constructor variable and i response: 'NameError: name 'self' is not defined'

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tools import read_file


class XmlParser:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(self.xml_file, self.parser_type)

    def __init__(self, file_name, parser_type):
        self.xml_file = read_file(file_name)
        self.parser_type = parser_type
```

How can i create my soup variable before constructor assignment?

Comment: `self` is only valid inside the instance methods. It can not be used on class level. attributes there are class attributes and shared among all instances of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My XmlParser receive file name and then read by filename and then create my soup for different methods.

In that case the `BeautifulSoup` instance should be the only class variable. In your methods you then can refer to it as `self.soup`. There is no need to expose `file_name` and `parser_type` to any other methods due to they are only specific to the `BeautifulSoup` instantiation which happens inside of the constructor `__init__`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tools import read_file

class XmlParser:    
  def __init__(self, file_name, parser_type):
    xml_file = read_file(file_name)
    self.soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_file, parser_type)

  def method_1(self):
    # access self.soup here

  def method_2(self):
    # access self.soup here
```